# Get the feed value from particular string in php

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, find

I have the below feed value

```
<item> 
 <description>&lt;strong&gt;Contact Number:&lt;/strong&gt; +91-00-000-000&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Rate:&lt;/strong&gt; xx.xx&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Fees and Comments:&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;$0 fees&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Indicative Exchange Rate&lt;/li&gt;</description>
</item>
```

Now i wanna get Contact number and rate as well as Fees and comments in separte value.

how can i get this value ..any one????

Comment: You could use a library for this: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: you should use an xml parser to extract description node and then use simple string methods to extract your relevant data....dont use regex for this..

Answer (score 0):

## Description

You should probably read this with a parsing engine. however if your use case is this simple then this regex will:

- capture each of the fields
- allow the fields to appear in any order

`^(?=.*?Contact\sNumber:<\/strong>([^<]*))(?=.*?Rate:<\/strong>([^<]*))(?=.*?Fees\sand\sComments:.*?<li>([^<]*)<.*?<li>([^<]*)<)`

[image]

Live Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/j0aStij3L8

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on what reliable patterns there are to the rest of your feed (or future feeds). It doesn't look like an XML parser is going to work here as the example doesn't look like well formed XML.
A good way to start is using explode to split the string into an array of strings, it looks like 
 is a good delimiter to split on. So this would look like:

```
$split_feed = explode("<br />",$feed);
```

where $feed is your feed input in the question, and $split_feed will be your output array.

Then, from that split feed, you can use strpos (or stripos) to test for keys in your string, to determine which field it references, and replace to get the value out of the key/value string.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think this is you want   
 <?php

    $value = '<strong>Contact Number:</strong> +91-00-000-000<br /><br />
              <strong>Rate:</strong> xx.xx<br /><br />
              <strong>Fees and Comments:<br /></strong><ul><li>$0 fees</li>
                <li>Indicative Exchange Rate</li>';

    $steps = explode('<br /><br />', $value);
    $step_2_for_contact_number = explode('</strong>', $steps[0]);

    $contact_number = $step_2_for_contact_number[1];

    $step_for_rate = explode('</strong>', $steps[1]);

    $rate = $step_for_rate[1];

    $feed_n_comment_s_1 = explode('</li>', $steps[2]);

    $feed_n_comment_s_2 = explode('<li>', $feed_n_comment_s_1[0]);

    $feed_n_comment = $feed_n_comment_s_2[1];

    echo $contact_number;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $rate;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $feed_n_comment;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at this pattern: (uses named groups)

```
(?<key>[a-zA-Z\d\s]+)(?=\:).*?\>(?<value>[^<]+)
```

#### [Live Demo](http://rubular.com/r/KPH31yS6ea)